# Custom Script For PDF loading in WordPress: Failed to load PDF document

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, header

**What I need:**
I need a PHP script, that can load some PDF files stored in a specific directory.
For example if I go to URL [www.mydomainameweb.com/wp-content/themes/elegant/pdf.php?file=a.pdf](http://www.mydomainameweb.com/wp-content/themes/elegant/pdf.php?file=a.pdf) (or [www.mydomainameweb.com/pdf?file=a.pdf](http://www.mydomainameweb.com/pdf?file=a.pdf) URL for me doesn't matter so much)
This should load the PDF file with header() function.

**What I did:**
I made a new PHP script /templates/elegant/page-pdf.php (my script)
And I also created WordPress page with URL “pdf”. So when I am loading mydomainameweb.com/pdf, this loads page-pdf.php script.
All good except this script in WP doesn’t load PDF file. Using this script in another domain without WP – works great.

I don't know why script returns error "Failed to load PDF document". While in external domain using the same script works great. Problem is only integrating with WordPress.

**page-pdf.php script content:**

```
// I hope that $file path is good, because when I set truly incorrect path it returns error that no such a file.
$name_file = 'name.pdf';
if (mime_content_type($file) == 'application/pdf')
  {

    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false); // These lines I add only in WP script file
    status_header(200); // These lines I add only in WP script file
    // Header content type
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $name_file . '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

    // Read the file
    @readfile($file);
  }
```

**UPDATE:**
What I tried now:

Created dublicated script and tried to open it directly:
[www.mydomainpagename12345.com/wp-content/themes/elegant/test.php](http://www.mydomainpagename12345.com/wp-content/themes/elegant/test.php)

I got this error:
Warning: mime_content_type(wp-content/themes/elegent/all_files/this-dir/file.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/myprojects/domains/mydomainpagename12345.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/elegant/test.php on line 37

But when I am opening directly the PDF, I can see the file:
mydomainpagename12345.com/wp-content/themes/elegent/all_files/this-dir/file.pdf

**UPDATE number 2:**
I tried to store and set only one file in the same directory with PHP script:
$file = 'a.pdf';
And great. This script works. But the problem is that now I didn't get $_SESSION data opening test.php script directly. Why did I lost session data opening PHP file directly?
[www.mydomainameweb.com/wp-content/themes/elegant/test.php?file=a.pdf](http://www.mydomainameweb.com/wp-content/themes/elegant/test.php?file=a.pdf) Loses $_SESSION['my_session'] WHY? What to do?

Comment: I'm guessing this probably has something to do with WP having output the general page header already at this point, or something similar. IMHO a bad idea to try and do this via a "page" to begin with; should rather set up a custom endpoint for something like this, https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Comment: _"I don't know why why script returns error "Failed to load PDF document"."_ - but you could probably easily _find out_, if you checked the error log, and what the response the server gave _actually_ contained (for example using your browser dev tools.) If any error messages made it into the output, then of course no application will be able to display this as a PDF any more.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/ - this one I was trying to read, but still don't understand. I am not so good in WordPress. Also I tried to check Chrome Console when loading this page. It shows empty. Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I spent 2-3 days with this issue.
I had to load external PHP. It was no problem. Problem was that external script doesn't get SESSION from WordPress. Spending few days with this issue got me a very simple solution. In the beginning of the external (same domain, but not in WP structure) PHP file you need too add two things:

1. Load wp-load.php file. That allows to work with WP settings and SESSIONS.
2. Add template comment session if this file is inside the template directory. In the beginning below, comment is not full. You should use your comment section according to your template.

Nobody helped me. But I will leave this solution if anybody needs it in the future.

**SOLUTION:**

```
<?php
require_once(rtrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/') . '/wp-load.php');
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
.....
```